# WebClient c# Send post with \n without making new line

Tags: c#, webclient

I try to send a json that contains a \n in it but when i send it webclient makes a linebreak where \n is i want to send the example:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                {    
                    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "*/*";
                    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage] = "en-US,en;q=0.5";
                    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "deflate";
                    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";

                    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
                    string textToSend = "This is a Test\n This is a Test2"
                    string sendString = textToSend;
                    byte[] responsebytes = wc.UploadData("https://localhost/", "POST",
                    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sendString));

                    string sret = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
                }
```

Outputs: This is a Test
This is a Test2

How can i make it output: This is a Test\n This is a Test2 ?

Comment: Escape '\n' by using '\\n' that way it'll preserve your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try escaping, pass `\\n` instead of `\n`. Is that what you want? Try using [Regex.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking of this but for some reason i never tested it. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

\n is an [Escape Sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

The character "\" is the escape character that is ignored when using strings. The character that follows it will usually give it a meaning. "\n" simply means newline.

To literally print this sequence, you must escape the escape sequence!

Use the escape character, like this:

```
string textToSend = "This is a Test\\n This is a Test2";
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using \n or \\n it is safe to use interpolated string

```
 string textToSend = $"This is a Test{Environment.NewLine} This is a Test2";
```

OR if you are on older version of C#

```
string textToSend = "This is a Test"+Environment.NewLine+ "This is a Test2";
```